# RxSwift Build an Observable based on a Variable

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am trying to build an Observable which would output a value based on the value of a Variable.

Something like that:

```
let fullName = Variable<String>("")
let isFullNameOKObs: Observable<Bool>

isFullNameOKObs = fullName
            .asObservable()
            .map { (val) -> Bool in
                // here business code to determine if the fullName is 'OK'
                let ok = val.characters.count >= 3
                return ok
            }
```

**Unfortunately the bloc in the map func is never called!**

The reason behind this is that:

1. The fullName Variable is binded to a UITextField with the bidirectional operator <-> as defined in the RxSwift example.
2. The isFullNameOKObs Observable will be observed to **hide or display** the submit button of my ViewController.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

The model

```
class Model {

    let fullName = Variable<String>("")
    let isFullNameOKObs: Observable<Bool>

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init(){

        isFullNameOKObs = fullName
            .asObservable()
            .debug("isFullNameOKObs")
            .map { (val) -> Bool in
                let ok = val.characters.count >= 3
                return ok
            }
            .debug("isFullNameOKObs")


        isRegFormOKObs = Observable.combineLatest(
            isFullNameOKObs,
            is...OK,
            ... ) { $0 && $1 && ... }


        isRegFormOKObs
            .debug("isRegFormOKObs")
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe { (event) in
                // update the OK button
            }
            // removing this disposedBy resolved the problem
            //.disposed(by: DisposeBag())

    }
}
```

The ViewController:

```
func bindModel() -> Void {

    _ = txFullName.rx.textInput <-> model!.fullName
    ......

}
```

Comment: Resolved but I don't understand how.
I use the same pattern for each TextField of the form: an Observable named isMyTextFieldOK that computes some business rules. A final observable that is a combineLatest of all isMyTextFieldOK observables. I did attach a disposed(by: disposeBag) call on this last observable. Removing it resolved everything. But I don't know why. :-(

Answer (score 4):

Do you need the two-way binding between the `UITextField` and your `Variable`?

If not, I would suggest you try to just use `bindTo()` instead like this:
`myTextField.rx.text.orEmpty.bindTo(fullName).disposed(by: disposeBag)`

Comment: Doesn't change. The Variable is correctly updated by the UITextField. But the value of Observable still doesn't reflect the correct situation.

Comment: How do you bind `isFullNameOKObs` to your button? Please share the code you're using

Comment: Still haven't determined how to do it.

Comment: The correct way, as I've learned it, is this:
`isFullNameOKObs.bindTo(myButton.rx.isEnabled).disposed(by: disposeBag)`. 

Regarding your comment about the removal of `disposed(by: disposeBag)`: this may be because your prematurely disposing your subscriptions, ie. by setting `disposeBag = nil` in your code.